# Filter all object form django modal if its id is not available to other table and on some conditions

Tags: django

```
Comments(models.Model):
   comments = models.CharField(max_length=55)

UsedComment(model.Model):
   bot = model.ForeignKey(InstagramBot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   comment_id = model.ForeignKey(Comments, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to filter all the comments from Comments Model if its id is not used by same bot in UsedComment. I mean comment can be repeated, but same bot can not use same comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to filter all the comments from Comments Model if its id is not
>   used by same bot in UsedComment. I mean comment can be repeated, but
>   same bot can not use same comment

You can use [`~Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) in filter

```
from django.db.models import Q
Comments.objects.filter(~Q(usedcomment__bot=your_bot))
```

Comment: can you please add exclude portion in different line

Comment: Comments.objects.filter(botscomment__bot_id=11).exclude(botscomment__comment_id__in=Comments.objects.all())

Comment: It gives empty output

Answer (score 2):

You can filter with:

```
Comments.objects.filter(usedcomment=None)
```

This works since Django will perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and thus the `Comments` for which there is no related `UsedComment` object, will have `NULL` as primary key.

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Comment` instead of <s>`Comments`</s>.

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
>   will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
>   be `comment`, instead of <s>`comment_id`</s>.

You can obtain the `Comments` objects that have been used multiple times by the same robot with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F

Comments.objects.annotate(
    ncomm=Count('usedcomment'),
    nbot=Count('usedcomment__bot', unique=True)
).filter(nbot__lt=F('ncomm'))
```

Comment: thank you for your help but my requirements is little bit changed

Comment: @SandeepPrasadKushwaha: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. I hope the edit works.

Comment: Sorry, here is mis understanding,  suppose there are two bot whose id are 1, 2 respectively. and Now i want to filter all the comments for bot 2, here  comment may be used or not used by first bot it doesn't matter, but comment should not used by second bot